# Word for "after one's career"

Tags: synonyms

*Posthumous* is the word used to denote that something occurred after someone's death. Is there a word that could be used for after one's career? The best I got is *postcurricular*, but I think that is more specific towards after one's schooling.

Here is an example of what I am shooting for:

> He received the award posthumously.
>
> He received the email post *_*_?

As a side note, I could use *post employment*, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: He received the award **in retirement**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is a pretty good one.

Comment: But it doesn't fit OP's request for an analogue to *"humously"* (which imho makes the question too localised, so I've voted to close).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: how is that too localized? Also, they're just looking to fill a lexical gap. so what if it doesn't fit exactly what they asked for; you've given an analog to posthumously which is good enough.

Comment: @Mitch: Everyone dies, and they certainly can't argue about their status there. But many people never really have a specific date before death, but after which their "career" is definitely over. No single word or expression can really be suitable for all contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really determined to use a *post-* prefix, I suppose you could say *postvocationally*.

Comment: Kinda falls into the postcirricular category, but I can see it.

Comment: I kinda hate to downvote a good try here, but apparently [post-vocationally](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I0VLAAAAYAAJ&q=%22post+vocationally%22&dq=%22post+vocationally%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RlSET43QAejQ0QWDp5TZBw&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCA) has already been co-opted to mean *after **starting** in the work environment*, not after leaving it.

Answer (score 2):

Before reading @FumbleFingers *in retirement*, I would have said *post-retirement*. I would consider his comment better, but thought I'd throw this out for your consideration.

Comment: Except that post-retirement means after retirement- with retirement refering to the full period of one's life after they've retired and not to the act of retiring itself.  So post-retirement would be 'in death'

Comment: Retirement can refer to the action or the state; both NOAD and M-W define it as action first and then state (both linking them very closely, however). I don't think my answer is wrong, and if used in context, I think there is little opportunity for confusion.